# Array and string

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-arrays

I have an array of type `char` and a string that I will be introducing from the keyboard. Can anyone tell me how can I introduce each character of the string in the `char` array?

Comment: @Damodar: [Just for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) [future reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

Comment: @Bobby : but this is not gud for every silly question making others alram. Its very very basic qestion, i can understand he is not familiar,we should not make them lazy just providing the answer from us with such questions. I feel ,there should be some self digging  nature to the people. Not to depend on others.

Comment: @Damodar it is not a silly question. It is a beginner's question. If you feel this question is too easy for you - and the title suggests it IS a basic question - then move on to any of thousands of more difficult questions.

Comment: @Damodar: That's an ongoing dispute and discussion. [Too simple question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42311/), [General Reference close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/), [Are some questions too simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). May I also quote from the downvote-tooltip: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`.

Comment: @Steve McLeod :  My intention was not make people lazy by providing answers for simple questions, they should incorporate some self digging/learning habit, because, if we google such questions, there will be 100s of answers available from different sites.Also people will learn more on self learning.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to create an array in advance. Here is the code

```
String s; //this is your string which you enter from keyboard

char[] c=s.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

[`string.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) will convert a String to a char array.

Alternatively, iterate over the string's characters and store them into your array:

```
char[] myArray = ...
int index = ... 
for(int i = 0 ; i < string.length() ; i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    myArray[index] = c;
    index++;
}
```